# Illegal start of simple expression when when defining new value in if-statement

Tags: scala, if-statement

I'm trying to declare a new value in an if-statement, but get the Illegal start error with the following code.

```
// df(: DataFrame) is defined earlier
if (df.columns.contains(f"original_cols_$prev_k%s"))
  val df_fixed = df.drop(f"original_cols_$prev_k%s").drop(f"scaled_cols_$prev_k%s")
else // No change, but to respect the immutability...
  val df_fixed = df
```

If I wrap it in the wave brackets ...

```
if (df.columns.contains(f"original_cols_$prev_k%s")){
  val df_fixed = df.drop(f"original_cols_$prev_k%s").drop(f"scaled_cols_$prev_k%s")
} else { // No change, but to respect the immutability...
  val df_fixed = df
}
```

... I don't get errors in these rows but later on get the "not found: value df_fixed"-error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if...else...` is an expression, not a statement. Therefore `val df_fixed = if (...) ... else ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala [expressions](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html) are composed of operators and operands. A conditional expression (`if-else`) expects other expressions after `if` and `else`. In the first case, you are using a definition (eg: `val int = 10`), when an expression is expected. This was the cause of the first error.

But by putting the definition inside curly braces you made it a block expression, so the compiler doesn't complain anymore.

```
if(true) {
  val integer = 10
}
```

However, `integer` has a local scope and is not available outside. Thus the second error of `not found`.

What you need is:

```
val integer = 
  if(somecheck()) 
    10 
  else 
    20
```