# Scala function fails when changing return type from Unit to String

Tags: scala, recursion, compiler-errors

I a teaching myself Scala, and have been dealing with the algorithmic problem of finding all balanced pairs of n parenthesis.

So, the following solution works:

```
object GetAllValidParenthesis extends App {
  def generateParenthesis(n: Int): Unit = {

    parenthesis("", 0, 0, n)

  }
  
  private def parenthesis(output: String, open: Int, close: Int, pairs: Int): Unit = {
    if ((open == pairs) && (close == pairs)) {
      println(output)
    }
    else {
      if (open < pairs) parenthesis(output + "(", open + 1, close, pairs)
      if (open > close) parenthesis(output + ")", open, close + 1, pairs)
    }
  }

  println(generateParenthesis(3))
}
```

But, if I wanted to return a String instead of Unit (so as to later keep all strings in some data structure, like an array buffer), i.e., I did this:

```
private def parenthesis(output: String, open: Int, close: Int, pairs: Int): String = {
    if ((open == pairs) && (close == pairs)) {
      output
    }
    else {
      if (open < pairs) parenthesis(output + "(", open + 1, close, pairs)
      if (open > close) parenthesis(output + ")", open, close + 1, pairs)
    }
  }
```

The compiler tells me:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
      if (open > close) parenthesis(output + ")", open, close + 1, pairs)
```

But it is impossible for the function to return anything but a String, since the only "return" is in the line that says "output", the rest are recursive calls.

Why does this happen? Is there any way in which I could fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If-else is a conditional expression in Scala. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70301435/757071

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, I learned something ;)

Comment: Hint: what do you return when `open == pairs` and `close != pairs`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, so, what you're saying is that the return type is undefined when the uppermost condition is not met - thus the compiler complaining? Yeah, I guess it makes sense xD, thanks, Jörg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, every expression has a value.

That's to say

```scala
// this is not a Boolean value
val exp = if (2 > 1) true

// in fact, is the same as following. The `Unit` and `Boolean`'s common type is `AnyVal`
val exp: AnyVal = if (2 > 1) true else {}
```

In your problem, your function should generate a string of parenthesis and append it to result set rather than just return the value.

I have just write [solution](https://github.com/counter2015/LeetCodeScala/blob/6a3ff3d28a7b378490105684d080418c287680d8/solutions/21-30/GenerateParenthesis.md) of this problem.

May be it's more appropriate like following

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object GenerateParenthesis {

  def generateParenthesis(n: Int): List[String] = {

    val res = ArrayBuffer.empty[String]

    def travel(l: Int, r: Int, curString: String): Unit = {
      if (l == 0 && r == 0) res += curString
      if (l > 0) travel(l - 1, r, curString + "(")
      if (r > l) travel(l, r - 1, curString + ")")
    }

    travel(n, n, "")
    res.toList
  }
}
```

The test code can be found here:

https://github.com/counter2015/LeetCodeScala/blob/6a3ff3d28a7b378490105684d080418c287680d8/src/test/scala/algorithms/medium/implementation/GenerateParenthesisTest.scala

Comment: Wow, worked like a charm, thanks so much!!